# How to make typed object map from array of pairs?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an array of pairs like that:

```
const attributes = [
  ['Strength', 'STR'],
  ['Agility', 'AGI'],
  ['Intelligence', 'INT']
  // ..
] as const;
```

And I want to generate something like that:

```
const attributesMap = {
  Strength: {
    name: 'Strength',
    shortName: 'STR',
  },
  Agility: {
    name: 'Agility',
    shortName: 'AGI',
  },
  // ..
};
```

And it should be fully typed, so if I want to access `attributesMap.Strength.shortName` I will know that it will be `"STR"`

How this could be typed?

The best I've come up with is this, but it does not really work as intended, because only key is typed as const value, `shortName` is still union of all the values and I don't know how to make it non union value:

```
type mapType = {
  [P in typeof attributes[number][0]]: {
    name: P;
    shortName: typeof attributes[number][1];
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
type mapType = {
  [P in typeof attributes[number][0]]: {
    name: P;
    // Wrap with Extract here
    shortName: Extract<typeof attributes[number], readonly [P, unknown]>[1];
  };
};
```

results in

```
type mapType = {
    Strength: {
        name: "Strength";
        shortName: "STR";
    };
    Agility: {
        name: "Agility";
        shortName: "AGI";
    };
    Intelligence: {
        name: "Intelligence";
        shortName: "INT";
    };
}
```

Comment: Nice approach with `Extract` type!

Comment: Although other answers do the job too, this one is very clever and easy to understand, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@A_Blop's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65168218/2887218) is correct; I just wanted to follow up with a version that uses TypeScript 4.1's [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) feature as an alternative to using `Extract`. Given:

```
const attributes = [
    ['Strength', 'STR'],
    ['Agility', 'AGI'],
    ['Intelligence', 'INT']
    // ..
] as const;
```

Let's give the type of `attributes` a name we can use later, and to make the remapping easier, let's restrict it so it only has the numeric literal keys (i.e., `0`, `1`, `2`) of each element, and not any of the `Array` keys like `push`, `pop`, etc:

```
type Atts = Omit<typeof attributes, keyof any[]>;
/* type Atts = {
    readonly 0: readonly ["Strength", "STR"];
    readonly 1: readonly ["Agility", "AGI"];
    readonly 2: readonly ["Intelligence", "INT"];
} */
```

Armed with `Atts`, we can now do the remapping with an `as` clause.  For every key `I` in `Atts`, the type `Atts[I][0]` is the key/`name`, and the type `Atts[I][1]` is the `shortName`:

```
type MappedAttributes = {
    -readonly [I in keyof Atts as Atts[I][0]]: {
        name: Atts[I][0],
        shortName: Atts[I][1]
    }
};

/*
type MappedAttributes = {
    Strength: {
        name: "Strength";
        shortName: "STR";
    };
    Agility: {
        name: "Agility";
        shortName: "AGI";
    };
    Intelligence: {
        name: "Intelligence";
        shortName: "INT";
    };
}
*/
```

(I've also removed `readonly` but you don't have to do that if you don't want to).  And that's the type you wanted!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhlKAnAlgIwK5QKYRgXhgG0BYAKBkuIHIBlZbMAcygAtqAaGOgFQCVqAXQ7kqNAIJMUAGxRQAnp27iA4gEkhIilSLU1YHNNlNGwbEr0A5HkNFUA9PZgA6Z+UHw8oSFADc5ALIFAAdsGHFEPEIAeQBbOQAeEOwQADN4RFRMHAguAGtseTT4MHkiQQA+fzJ7ACoYZPDIghgAbztKJGw4ABNwaXkYAAYALhgu3v7BogAiei7mNhmuOf4ZwWqxCb6wAZgARjHtqeIZyRk5eWWYM-V1zapj3cGAJiPunb3Z-UNjU2xrjM1NZ7uQAL4wWr2QKNACycGCoR6EWQ6CwuBa7W0lAAtE8vmoYCgwDACkV0ii8HA8JSiGpBEQhoJBGMsWIxGA4LFsGNafTGcIOuyIKwQEgoJYuTymlAIHSGftBEKweDquQ6uQ4QikSisuiom0hfNGCxWKyhRypWM5gxFqwZg92TARWKJVabrQ1o6YGDvedZApzdj2Zzudb-ZcHRaqC7xZKwzdVGoo8HfUKftgjCgTGAzEGnZRQ9KgQZM39cwDvWJY26E0CQd602QVWQoYEgA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive type:

```
type MapType<T extends readonly (readonly [string, unknown])[]> = 
    // if the list can be split into a head and a tail
    T extends readonly [readonly [infer A, infer B], ...infer R]
        // these should always be true but typescript doesn't know that
        ? A extends string ? R extends readonly (readonly [string, unknown])[]
            ? {
                // this'll be just one property
                [K in A]: {
                    name: A,
                    shortName: B
                }
            // we intersect with the type recursed on the tail
            } & MapType<R>
            // these should never happen
            : never : never
        // base case, empty object
        : {};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhlKAnAlgIwK5QKYRgXhgG0AoGYgcgGVlswBzKACwoBoZqAVAJQoF1WZSgEF6KADYooATzYdhAcQCS-QeSIUlYHOMn06wbHM0A5TvyEB6SzAB0tkn3h5QkKAG4SJGQAdsMAFk4H05pPwAeThhsAA8cMAATPCRsOATwcWkYAAoUtIysomhUBnYMMABrMBAAdzA+AEoiPgA+AhghcmsYFAAzGGZ-SWgYYDgwGDR-CB9JWBRtEHgYJlSE+ETlqDgJTpgo2PikmDz0sEziU4LiBd7sJBhhdlv7mAAhATt7F4fuPj3yF0bIMINMmCAMOJ1nBxDU4NI8FMBkgMP5MLBfLhgKgfLB0rgwBRYFVagMmAgAYCAPyPaJxOjHYoLegwGncOlHZJra65bnnQpM0owcokuqNZqUwHUmAAb0lUoV3WYKAgFF0k38ACsMCNwP4fEgQH4kDJ5QrAUQANI9CbCPgALllZvNCrAcAAtthHU9nS7ARBwSaTB6ve9fQqAL7h7o1fwLHBIUHAWA1KRMMn+TEnbDADCJ7DrcAZgY7cThiMwABkgWCoQi3Ba0eBq1BMADEKhMDA2AAbq9yT4-GBw47u32HqPe-d5d00HBW2NQexsO7cVkQGhNTmoPLHTKI54-VKvFmABrtIIhMLYcKYkD9BDIdBYXAtTwkJVILLAckMZmWFJ3RAHtmQ2dd+hBfwexhVE8HGdZBhSNVxA1DZoiQQ0kBIVwRl6EAQEdc9CDlKUaBSBhmD3eU3U9R0ACIyLoRgmDotQXXbIMQ3oqgeDovYIzY8hRAkKRpCov0aNDOjhLmaRWPlDioGDWiYGk5Q+KlAS9i0HQ9AMUMSJdST6J07BdBQfQwEMeS-UU5SpKUMwNMBKMDyAA)

Alternatively, to avoid repeating `readonly`, you can make a type that recursively gets rid of it:

```
type RemoveReadonly<T> = T extends readonly unknown[] ? {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: RemoveReadonly<T[K]>;
} : T;

type MapType<T extends [string, unknown][]> = 
    // if the list can be split into a head and a tail
    T extends [[infer A, infer B], ...infer R]
        // these should always be true but typescript doesn't know that
        ? A extends string ? R extends [string, unknown][]
            ? {
                // this'll be just one property
                [K in A]: {
                    name: A,
                    shortName: B
                }
            // we intersect with the type recursed on the tail
            } & MapType<R>
            // these should never happen
            : never : never
        // base case, empty object
        : {};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhlKAnAlgIwK5QKYRgXhgG0AoGYgcgGVlswBzKACwoBoZqAVAJQoF1WZSgEF6KADYooATzYdhAcQCS-QeSIUlYHOMn06wbHM0A5TvyEB6SzAB0tkn3h5QkKAG4SJGQAdsMbmwAWxAAN2xAuAATcHFpAB5OAD4CGE4YbAAPHDAovCRsaNjpGAwwAGswEAB3MCInAH4YAG8hcgBaAqKwOOIAaRgUMBhy7GkQADM0vgAuAOCwiMKYnoTOIj6+JM8AXxg5zk9vaT8YAFk4H04T7ESM7Lo84mhUBnYyypqwPnqUwjaYNZBlNmP5JNAYMA4MM0P4ID5JLAhlAQPAYExlvBcmioHAJAD0lkck8iEQhhNsEgYMJ2OTKTAAEICOz2OlU7h8AHkchA0EQOFMEAYcRReDiapwaR4WEwZAYfyYWC+XDAVA+WAxXBgCiwT7VWVMBBc7lNYT3Yl4F5DegwJrcc2PPBEK1vUoVKq1H6c7k+31NVq+wO+3lMFAQCi6GAygBWGAh4H8PiQID8SBkxqD3I2g2GwlmLQzmd9YDgQWwcxphaL3IggrTJlL5cZVaDOxbPJs1X8yMp-OAsGqUiYBv8ypgBWAGCQ-NF4BHsrx4nbMD2ADJzpdrn54twksuQ7gBUKRTAwNhwlTDT4-GBl3Mzxf9qfz5TC0C0HB+ZDP9h2MF1SUIBoNG2D9oWczNDsnjVuQXhjgAGqkFxXDcO4LOEkQrHE8TKpM8CIKgiq4Ek2xeLySAlMAhoMNalgFCEoTWligEghiX6hHA4jyng0KiqCBQRuIUb+NCGRIMmSAkK4EITCAIBzIhhABtyNAFAwzAQYWJZlnMABEql0IwTC6WoQa1iA9aNnpVA8LpAI7KZ5CiBIUjSJpmbaU2unOYi0gmYW5mWTpMDecodk+g5AJaDoegGE2ymBp5enRdgugoPoYCGP5maBVADbBbpShmOF3JtlBQA)